# AngularJS - Horizontally scrolling div indicators

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, scroll

I'm building an AngularJS (among other things) powered site with a table in it, which is a bit too wide to display on devices with smaller screens.
Therefore I made it horizontally scrollable when the parent element, the page's main content block, is too narrow to fit the table `div`.

HTML:

```
<fieldset ng-show="tels.length > 0">
    <div class="table-wrapper">
        <div class="table" ng-repeat="type in types">
            <div class="form-group control-group"
                ng-repeat="tel in tels | filter:{type:type.name} | orderBy:'label'">
                <div>{{tel.label}}</div>
                <div>{{tel.value}}</div>
                <div>{{tel.description}}</div>
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

CSS:

```
.table-wrapper {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.table-wrapper .table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    min-width: 500px;
    padding-right: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.table-wrapper .table > div {
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

This works, but because the scrollbar isn't always visible, and there's not always some cut-off content to hint at the table being scrollable, I want to add some indicators dynamically when it's possible to scroll the table, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OujCw.jpg) or [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5cGm.png) (but then horizontally)

To monitor the table's scroll position, I added a **watcher** to my angular code:

```
$scope.$watch($('.table-wrapper'), function() {
    var scrolled = angular.element('.table-wrapper').scrollLeft();
    $log.info("scrolled: " + scrolled);
});
```

This does seem to log the table's horizontal position, but only initially:

```
scrolled: 0
```

It doesn't update when I scroll the table, even though the DOM Element's `scrollLeft` property does reflect its position when inspected.

Strangely, the following jQuery code does log the horizontal scroll position upon scrolling, and I can get it to work as in this [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Keledin/2xuakdej/1/) (reduce the size of the output screen):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.table-wrapper').on('scroll', function() {
        var scrolled = $('.table-wrapper').scrollLeft();
        console.log("scrolled: " + scrolled);
    });
});
```

No such luck in AngularJS.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is your div with the class `tableDiv` ?

Comment: Whoops, forgot to update the code I pasted, as I changed some names for improved clarity. I've changed it to match the rest. Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 0):

below code will not work in this case,
try using events for scrollbar or use bootstrap with `table-responsive` class

```
$scope.$watch($('.scroll-horizontal'), function() {
    var scrolled = angular.element('.scroll-horizontal').scrollLeft();
    $log.info("scrolled: " + scrolled);
});
```

try using something like this

```
    function logScroll(ev){
      if(window.pageYOffset>400)alert('User has scrolled at least 400 px!');
    }
    window.onscroll=logScroll
```

Comment: window.pageYOffset is for the entire page in the Y direction. It works, but when I try that on the scrollable table in the X direction, it doesn't.

Comment: ghost, use your logic to get offset of your table there and it will work

Comment: Could you give an example?